# Finding a seg fault in a small code

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am unable to get the source of segmentation fault in this short cuda code. 
I am using it to test the sorting speed of the Thrust library versus the STL library for
sorting integers. I am passing the size of the array of doubles to be sorted as a command line 
argument.

Here is the code

```
inline void check_cuda_error(char *message)

    {
      cudaThreadSynchronize();
      cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
      if(error != cudaSuccess)
      {
        printf("CUDA error after %s: %s\n", message, cudaGetErrorString(error));
      }
    }



            int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
          int  N = atoi(argv[1]);
          double* h = new double[N];
          for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
              h[i] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX; //std::cout << h[i] << " " ;
            }

          clock_t start , stop;

          std::cout << std::endl;

          // Start timing
          start = clock();
          std::sort(h, h+N);
          stop  = clock();  
          std::cout << "Host sorting took " << (stop - start) /(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl ; 


          // Start the GPU work. Initialize to random numbers again.
          for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
              h[i] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX; //std::cout << h[i] << " " ;
            }
          double* d = 0; 
          const size_t num_bytes = N * sizeof( double ); 
          cudaMalloc((void**)&d, num_bytes);
          check_cuda_error("Memory Allocation"); 

          cudaMemcpy(d ,h , N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // Transfer data
          thrust::sort( d, d+ N ) ;
            return 0;
        }
```

I get the following errors

```
[BeamerLatex/Farber]$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 sortcompare.cu  ; ./a.out 16777216

Host sorting took 3.77
[1]    4661 segmentation fault  ./a.out 16777216
[BeamerLatex/Farber]$
```

Comment: just a guess but, could you please check the returnvalue of cudaMalloc. If it is cudaErrorMemoryAllocation the call to cudaMemcpy will most probably fail because destination will still be 0. Which will usually lead to a segfault.

Comment: not related, but you're not deleting `h`...

Comment: Can you add your includes? I cba to google them all, and it would help me to have a running version of the code

Comment: I am guessing your environment is not configured correctly. maybe check response of cudaMalloc?

Comment: Another vulnerability: if argv can't be converted to an integer by atoi(), you run into undefined behavior and anything can happen. Perhaps atoi() would return 0, I can see how that would cause seg faults and other mysterious bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you cannot run thrust::sort on a raw pointer, you need to cast it to `device_ptr` first, ie.:

```
thrust::device_ptr< double > dv = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d);
thrust::sort( dv, dv+ NN ) ;
```

this works fine for me.